# apt-get upgrade doesn't find newest packages

Tags: security, apt, embedded

Recently Debian Wheezy LTS released a new version of a package, e.g. wget 1.13.4-3+deb7u4 (see announcement [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-lts-announce/2017/03/msg00006.html)), on my system I still have an old version e.g. wget 1.13.4-3+deb7u3 installed.

My sources.list only have one line:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

My preferences file is not exiting at all.
I've used another sources.list file for regular security upgrades. When doing an `apt-get -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=security-sources.list update` it looks fine:

```
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main armel Packages
Reading package lists... Done
```

But when doing an `apt-get upgrade` or dist-upgrade it doesn't install newest package versions:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Also an `apt-cache policy wget` doesn't list the newest version:

```
wget:
  Installed: 1.13.4-3+deb7u3
  Candidate: 1.13.4-3+deb7u3
```

The problem is reproducible.

Why apt-get upgrade doesn't find and install newest version of the released packages, e.g wget deb7u4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
in the command `apt-get update` there was another sources.list file used with `-o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security-sources.list`
But `apt-get upgrade` was called without this other source.list file - I assumed it is not needed anymore - but it is.
Once I've used the same sources.list file for update and upgrade everything works fine.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to upgrade, the `armel` binaries weren’t ready yet: see the [pool contents](http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/w/wget/) (timestamps are UTC AFAIK), they were uploaded at 11:13 UTC. If you try the upgrade again now it should work.

Your `sources.list` is somewhat incomplete; the recommended settings for [Wheezy LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using) are

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

(take care when adding `arch` qualifiers, you’re liable to miss out on architecture-independent updates).

Comment: Thanks for your hints!
Even now it's not working, not with `[ arch=armel,all ]` and also not with all lines in sources.list

Comment: Now I was able to simplify the sources.list by removing the arch qualifies. There have been an old architecture defined in dpkg, which I deleted. Now it also works without this qualifier - but still doesn't upgrade to newest wget